# How to add a Folder to a script

Tags: batch-file

sorry about this but this is making me feel dump

I was given this script which is very helpful but for the life of me

I can seem to add a folder 
 I want to add `2Preparing` folder

No matter what I do the script fails to run

can you help me with this

Thank you

```
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir file.txt /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do for /L %%J in (1,1,%VariableV%) do copy "%%I" "%%~dpIfile (%%J).txt"
```

I like this script because I can control the outfile `file (1).txt`

Work Environment

```
Main Folder
+ ----2Preparing
       |   File.txt

Main Folder
+ ----2Preparing
       |    File (1).txt
       |    File (2).txt
       |    File.txt
```

Comment: What does this script do? What do you want it to do? What changes have you tried? What happened/did not happen?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe it can be fitted to do a few different things but in this case this script I changed it to be a copier so it will take `file.txt` and with `variable` I enter the number of copies I want to make and it does this `File (1).txt, File (2).txt etc..`

Comment: so I want to control it to a single folder and not every folder I could remove `/s` but I still can't make it work directly in a folder, I will type up a work space in my question

Comment: this section `"%%~dpIfile (%%J).txt"` lets me control the outfile

Comment: _"sorry about this but this is making me feel dump"_ you might want to see a doctor if this happens at unusual times. Jokes aside.. I don't get what you want to do with the folder. Are you wanting to create a folder or specifically only search for this folder? Your question is very erratic and unclear.

Comment: @Gerhard - all I want to do is isolate the script to read and scan 1 main folder call `2Preparing` right now the script will scan ever folder and I don't mind using `/s` but for as long as it only looks inside `2Preparing` folder

Comment: Then specify the folder and remove `/s` from the `dir` connand, as simple as that.

Comment: @Gerhard - yes I have tried to specify a folder and it fails, and I still need the `/s` to scan folders if any found inside `2Preparing`

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have figured out the reason

```
Original <br>
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir file.txt /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do for /L %%J in (1,1,%VariableV%) do copy "%%I" "%%~dpIfile (%%J).txt"

Temp 1 Failed <br>
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "2Preparing\file.txt" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do for /L %%J in (1,1,%VariableV%) do copy "%%I" "%%~dpIfile (%%J).txt"

Answer <br>
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%~dp02Preparing\file.txt" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do for /L %%J in (1,1,%VariableV%) do copy "%%I" "%%~dpIfile (%%J).txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run that script on a file in a folder that isn't in the same folder as the batch file, you could do this:

```
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "path\to\folder\file.txt" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do for /L %%J in (1,1,%VariableV%) do copy "%%I" "%%~dpIfile (%%J).txt"
```

Simply add the relative path from the batch file to the file you want to work on. If you want it to be a bit more smart, you can do this.

```
set count=0
set "path=path\to\folder"
set file=file
:loop
set count=%count%+1
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%path%\%file%.txt".txt /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do for /L %%J in (1,1,%VariableV%) do copy "%%I" "%%~dpIfile (%%J).txt"
if %count%==(however many files you want to process) goto:eof
if %count%==1 (
     set "path=path\to\another\folder"
     set file=anotherfile
    )
goto loop
```

This will let you make a list of every file and every path to those files you want to edit, and then the program will loop through, preforming each operation however many times you need. It would work the same to past your for command string a bunch of times, and set it up with one for each file too, but this way you only need to debug one command.

Comment: Hello and Thank you, I did try what you suggested `"path\to\folder\file.txt"` but this fails, this is why I feel dump, because I know what you suggested, but I just now realized why it failed it needs to be like this `"%~dp02Preparing\file.txt"` it was missing this `%~dp0`

Comment: Strange. I don't usualy need to use %~dp0 to locate the bat file. I'm glad you worked it out!